# spring security facebook error with session

Tags: facebook, grails, spring-security

am using spring security Facebook 0.6 , am able to get user authentication from facebook but when user tries to access my application  then it shows error as follows

```
2012-02-16 11:06:22,376 [http-8080-1] ERROR hibernate.LazyInitializationException  - could not initialize proxy - no Session

org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
        at 
org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:86)
        at 
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.proxy.HibernateProxyHandler.unwrapProxy(HibernateProxyHandler.java:83)
        at 
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsHibernateUtil.unwrapProxy(GrailsHibernateUtil.java:404)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsHibernateUtil$unwrapProxy.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:40)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsHibernateUtil$unwrapProxy.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.orm.hibernate.HibernatePluginSupport$__clinit__closure94.doCall(HibernatePluginSupport.groovy:397)
```

Comment: Is user object stored in session !

Comment: Can you show code where it's throwing this exception?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be trying to access the user object which is stored in session, can you show us the code.

Try reattaching the detached user object before you access any of the fields.

```
//get user from session
user.attach()
```